# Yesod: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in browser when sending large JSON body

Tags: json, haskell, browser, yesod

I'm sending a large JSON body (~3MB) in a production app (it's a base64 encoded file). When I send a JSON body, Yesod seems to think this worked:

```
POST /send-json
  Accept: */*
  Status: 200 OK 0.000098s
```

But the browser doesn't get a response back and instead gets `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. I've reproduced this in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Could this be a bug somewhere, in maybe warp or wai? My expectation would be that if Yesod is configured with:

```
maximumContentLength _ _ = Just (10 * 1024 * 1024) -- 10 megabytes
```

that receiving a large request body shouldn't be a problem.

Version Info: https://gist.github.com/MaxGabriel/10e8a999eabcc9cb566c087978f5c3ac

LTS: LTS-Haskell 9.14

I reproduced this issue in this repo here: https://github.com/MaxGabriel/large-files. It's the yesod-simple template with just 1 additional commit: https://github.com/MaxGabriel/large-files/commit/38addf762feaa5cbff19b84821c7980eec10b160. Instead of sending a file, I just copy a string a bunch of times to create a huge JSON body (a few megabytes).

I can't reproduce this issue sending a binary file in a form.

I can't reproduce this issue from `curl`.

EDIT: If I actually consume the body using `requireCheckJsonBody`, then the issue goes away. If I ignore the body and just `return ()` then I get the error. Because of this, I think there's a good chance this is a bug in Yesod or somewhere else in the stack

Comment: For people reading this, this is discussed on https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1479